# string comparison with special character

Tags: apex

I am trying check below string in the if condition but apparently it is not satisfying the string comparison condition even though system.debug shows the same string.

```
 String APH = test.substring(0,3);
 system.debug('inside APH '+ APH ); // outputs A&P
 if(APH == 'A&P '){
 system.debug('after substring '); // not printing
 }
```

I have even tried to do this but still not working

```
if(APH == 'A\\&P '){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison has an extra whitespace after the string you're actually looking for

`'A&P '` is the problem, it should be `'A&P'`

That said, you could probably make whatever it is you're trying to do simpler (and more reliable) by simply using `String.contains()`.

e.g.
`if(test.contains('A&P')){ // do work }`

Comment: well that whitespace was intentional but anyway your contains() suggestion turns out to be working fine.

Comment: @Akash `substring(0,3)` would return a string of length 3 (zero indexed, and it stops at `endIndex - 1`), so comparing it to a string of length 4 will obviously never return true.

Comment: m confused, how is it 4 ? A-0,&-1,P-2, -3. Am I Correct? I was trying intentionally compare 'A&P ' with 'A&P ' from the substringed variable. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Akash Like I said, `substring(0, 3)` returns indexes 0-2 (end index is 3, the documentation says the result is from the start index to end index - 1). Your given substring() call returns a string of length 3, not 4. You can check that for yourself by using `system.debug(APH.length());` `'A&P '` is a length of 4. Strings of different lengths will _never_ be equal.